# Table not Echoing out if another Table has a Zero value

Tags: php, mysql

The HTML table below with `mysql_query($sqlStr3)` (the one with the word "Joined" in its row) does not echo if the result associated with `mysql_query($sqlStr1)` has a value of zero.  This happens even if `mysql_query($sqlStr3)` returns a result.

In other words, if a given loginid has an entry in the MySQL table "login", but not one in the MySQL table "submission", then the table associated with `mysql_query($sqlStr3)` does not echo.

I don't understand why the MySQL "submission" table would have any effect on `mysql_query($sqlStr3)`, since the $sqlStr3 only deals with another MySQL table, called "login", as seen below.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance,

John W.

```
<?php

echo '<div class="profilename">User Profile for </div>';
echo '<div class="profilename2">'.$profile.'</div>';

$tzFrom = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 
$tzTo = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'); 

  $profile = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['profile']);

  $sqlStr = "SELECT l.username, l.loginid, s.loginid, s.submissionid, s.title, s.url, s.datesubmitted, s.displayurl
               FROM submission AS s
         INNER JOIN login AS l
                 ON s.loginid = l.loginid
              WHERE l.username = '$profile'
           ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC";

  $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt = new DateTime($row["datesubmitted"], $tzFrom); 
    $dt->setTimezone($tzTo);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename3">'.$dt->format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a').'</a></td>'; 
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";    

  $sqlStr1 = "SELECT l.username, l.loginid, s.loginid, s.submissionid, s.title, s.url, s.datesubmitted, s.displayurl, l.created, count(s.submissionid) countSubmissions
               FROM submission AS s
         INNER JOIN login AS l
                 ON s.loginid = l.loginid
              WHERE l.username = '$profile'";


  $result1 = mysql_query($sqlStr1);

$arr1 = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec2\">";
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename5">Submissions: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row1["countSubmissions"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";    


  $sqlStr2 = "SELECT l.username, l.loginid, c.loginid, c.commentid, c.submissionid, c.comment, c.datecommented, l.created, count(c.commentid) countComments
               FROM comment AS c
         INNER JOIN login AS l
                 ON c.loginid = l.loginid
              WHERE l.username = '$profile'";


  $result2 = mysql_query($sqlStr2);

$arr2 = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec3\">";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename5">Comments: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row2["countComments"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";    


$tzFrom3 = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 
$tzTo3 = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'); 


  $sqlStr3 = "SELECT created, username
               FROM login 
              WHERE username = '$profile'";


  $result3 = mysql_query($sqlStr3);

$arr3 = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec4\">";
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { 
    $dt3 = new DateTime($row3["created"], $tzFrom3); 
    $dt3->setTimezone($tzTo3);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename5">Joined: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$dt->format('F j, Y').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";    

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to echo out `$dt3->format('F j, Y')` instead of `$dt->format('F j, Y')` in one of the last lines of the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { 
    $dt3 = new DateTime($row3["created"], $tzFrom3); 
    $dt3->setTimezone($tzTo3);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename5">Joined: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$dt->format('F j, Y').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Are you looking to call $dt3->format('F j, Y') in the echo here, instead of $->format('F j, Y')? I don't see any other use for $dt3.